# Iteración de método MAP por cada valor de un Array

Tags: javascript, array, nodejs, api

Necesito reemplazar por valores vacíos distintas cadenas de un array de objetos.

Este es un ejemplo de uno de los objetos que tengo en mi respuesta JSON:

```
{
"data": [
{
"Section_B_Demographic_Details/formhub/uuid": "4f8640b7835742279e7058893957d633",
"Section_B_Demographic_Details/lugar_inscripcion": "mdhyh",
"Encuesta/Datos_Generales/nombre_apellido": "Juan Perez",
"Encuesta/Datos_Generales/tipo_up": "grupo_asociativo",
"Encuesta/Relevamiento/ESCALA_DE_PRODUCCI_N/nombre_up_emprend_negocio": "ConstruiMas",
"Encuesta/Relevamiento/ESCALA_DE_PRODUCCI_N/comienzo_activ_up": "2021-10-14",
"DEMANDA_P_BLICO_OBJETIVO/calle_up": "Soler",
"DEMANDA_P_BLICO_OBJETIVO/altura_up": "3919",

}
```

Esta información se repite en cada uno de los cientos que hay dentro del array. Para poder reemplazar todos, me ayudaron con la siguiente función:

```
const reemplazarStringNombreKey = (str, obj) => {
    const newObj = {};
    for(const propName in obj) {
      const newPropName = propName.replace(str, '');
      newObj[newPropName] = obj[propName];
    }
    return newObj;
  }
```

Luego, con un map al array de objetos:

```
const arrayObjNuevo = arrayObj.map(obj => reemplazarStringNombreKey(str, obj))
```

A esta función, el string, es uno solo de los valores que se repite en todos los objetos.

```
const str = 'Section_B_Demographic_Details/';
```

Si tuviera un array con los distintos valores:

```
const arrayStr = ['Section_B_Demographic_Details/', 'Encuesta/Datos_Generales/nombre_apellido', ....etc];
```

¿Cómo itero sobre ese arreglo para reemplazar todos los valores con la función anteriormente enviada?

Intenté de la siguiente manera, y no logro dar con el reemplazo:

```
arrayStr.forEach(cadena => arrayObj.map(obj=>reemplazarStringNombreKey(cadena, obj)));
```

Esto es con fin de no tener, como lo tengo actualmente, que ocupo varias constantes con las cadenas y luego un map encadenado a otro.

Comment: Entonces quieres reemplazar las keys por valores vacíos?

Comment: Quiero reemplazar una parte de las keys por valores vacíos, con fin de que en vez de: 
Section_B_Demographic_Details/lugar_inscripcion
Quede:
lugar_inscripcion

Comment: No es este un trabajo para `.flat()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías modificar el método actual que realiza el reemplazo para que en vez de una cadena reciba una lista de cadenas. De esa forma en una sola llamada puedes lograr el cometido.

Para ello nos apoyaremos en el método [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) del tipo Array, que devuelve el primer elemento de la lista que cumpla la condición. En este caso, la condición se establece usando el método [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) de String. Queremos que de la lista, nos devuelva la cadena que sea parte del nombre de la propiedad que estamos iterando. Si el nombre de la propiedad incluye la cadena de la lista, se devuelve esta cadena que será luego reemplazada en el nombre de la propiedad. De esta forma, en una sola llamada, pasas la lista de cadenas que deseas reemplazar y el objeto. Si el objeto no contiene entre los nombres de su atributo alguno de los elementos de la lista, establecemos el valor devuelto por `find` en una cadena vacía. Si la lista contiene cadenas que no están incluidas en el nombre del atributo, no se reemplaza nada.

Por ejemplo:

```js
const replaceStringFromKeyName = (strList, obj) => {
  const newObj = {};
  for(const propName in obj) {
    const str = strList.find(s => propName.includes(s)) || '';
    const newPropName = propName.replace(str, '');
    newObj[newPropName] = obj[propName];
  }
  return newObj;
}

const json = {
  "data": [
    {
      "formhub/uuid": "xxxxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/lugar_inscripcion": "xx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/nombre_apellido": "xx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/tipo_up": "xxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/nombre_up_emprend_negocio": "xxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/comienzo_activ_up": "xxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/calle_up": "xxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/altura_up": "xxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/dato_adic_ubicac_up": "xxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/comuna": "xx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/barrio": "xxxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/email_up": "xxx",
      "Section_B_Demographic_Details/red_social_up": "xxx"
    }
  ]
};
const strList = ['formhub/','Section_B_Demographic_Details/', 'notExist'];
const newData = json.data.map(obj => replaceStringFromKeyName(strList, obj));

console.log(newData);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  top: 0;
}
```

Como se aprecia en el código anterior, la lista de cadenas a reemplazar contiene 3 elementos, de los cuales sólo 2 forman parte de algún nombre de atributo. Se reemplazan únicamente aquellos que están en la lista y que sean parte del nombre.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Comment: Hola Mauricio! Cuanto conocimiento jaja, espero llegar algún día a eso.Muchas gracias por tus respuestas.. funciona, perfecto.